# Position a image next a textfield in a form

Tags: extjs6

I have a form with some text fields. One of them is a image upload button.
I need to put the image preview box (a div) to the right side of the field (after the field button).

I already do the hard work by creating the div in the `afterrender` event:

```
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function ( cmp ) {
            var container = this.body.dom.id;
            $("#" + container ).append('<div style="position:absolute;
                   left:DONTKNOW;top:DONTKNOW" id="myPictureDiv"></div>');
        }
    }
```

how can I position elements in a ExtJS form? Can I use `position:absolute` ? But how to find the button position? What about form resizing?

EDIT: Image to illustrate scebotari's solution alignment problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for this is to create the additional div as a component and to place it in a "fieldcontainer" with the main field.

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Picture'
    },{
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: 'div',
        width: 32,
        height: 32,
        margin: '0 0 0 5',
        style: 'border: 1px solid #d0d0d0; border-radius: 50%'
    }]
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ot1) illustrating this concept

Comment: Great! You rule! Can I give it an ID ? More elegant than my solution

Comment: Done. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I have a little problem in the field alignment. Please see the image I put in my question.

Comment: Solved: Just added `labelWidth: 90` to the `textfield` because I have this value in all my other fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Form field

```
    fieldLabel: 'My Field',
    width: 330,
    id: 'displayColumn',
    name: 'displayColumn',
    allowBlank : false,
    value : '#CACACA',
```

This is the form listener:

```
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function ( cmp ) {
            // Get the Window Container
            var container = this.body.dom.id;

            // Get the Component (ExtJS way)
            var comp = Ext.getCmp("displayColumn");
            // The ExtJS field ID is not the same you gave
            var el = comp.getEl();
            // Get the real Field ID 
            var displayColumnId = el.id;            
            // If you need its value...
            var initialColor = comp.getValue();

            // If you need to hide the field to make room to your div...
            // I mean if you want to replace the field and keep the label...
            // <YOUR_FIELD_ID>-triggerWrap
            $("#displayColumn-triggerWrap").css("display","none");

            // Append your div to the field container
            // <YOUR_FIELD_ID>-bodyEl
            $("#displayColumn-bodyEl").append(YOUR_DIV);
       }
}
```

Do some style to the div as you wish